# Iterating file paths in python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, iteration

I have a data frame that has all the file paths that is called filedataframe. My code works for pulling what I want from a individual xml file. But it is currently set up for a single file. **How do I make this where it will iterate through the data frame filedataframe to use the file path?** I want to add rootId, file_Name, unique_ID, and employee_badge with there respective file path.

```
import re
import pathlib
import os  
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

filesdataframe = []
# example path would be Defined Contributions,



xmlfile = (r'INVESTING.cdm')
    #WE are parseing it.
tree = ET.parse(xmlfile)
    #We then get the root.
root = tree.getroot()

for elm in root.findall('.//{object}IntraModelReport'):
        print(elm.text)


for Model in root.findall('.//{object}IntraModelReport'):
        rootId = elm.attrib
        file_Name = Model.find("{attribute}Code").text
        unique_ID = Model.find("{attribute}ObjectID").text
        employee_badge = Model.find("{attribute}Creator").text
        print(rootId,file_Name, unique_ID, employee_badge)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```py
import re
import pathlib
import os  
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from typing import Dict, List

def process_single_xmlfile(xmlfile: str, verbose: bool=False) -> Dict:
    tree = ET.parse(xmlfile)
    root = tree.getroot()

    for elm in root.findall('.//{object}IntraModelReport'):
        print(elm.text)

    package: Dict = {'xmlfile': xmlfile, 'models': []}
    for Model in root.findall('.//{object}IntraModelReport'):
        rootId = elm.attrib
        file_Name = Model.find("{attribute}Code").text
        unique_ID = Model.find("{attribute}ObjectID").text
        employee_badge = Model.find("{attribute}Creator").text
        if verbose:
            print(rootId, file_Name, unique_ID, employee_badge)
        package['models'].append(dict(
            rootId = rootId,
            file_Name = file_Name, 
            unique_ID = unique_ID,
            employee_badge = employee_badge,
        ))
    return package

#### LOOP OVER
        
# all the results will be stored in this list        
extracts: List[Dict] = []
# xmlfiles is a list of xml filenames: You need to provide this
# you can replace "xmlfiles" with your "filedataframe".
for xmlfile in xmlfiles:
    # set verbose=True to enable printing
    extracts.append(process_single_xmlfile(xmlfile, verbose=False))
```

Comment: I do need a little help of understanding what is going on. So on the line with package = dict I am getting a syntax error. Also so I have all the file paths in "filedataframe". Do I need to convert this data frame to a list called "xmlfiles"?

Comment: @StevenMarsh Yes, there was a typo in the line you mentioned. I just corrected it. You can replace `xmlfiles` with `filedataframe` and that will work as well. But if `filedataframe` is a list, you might want to change the name of the variable as the name `filedataframe` sounds like a dataframe of files.